# Jquery Nested li and ul tags not clicking

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a List Like this Which Basically Acts like a tree. Im using this jquery library
https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Expandable-Html-List-Element-Expandable-List/
which I combined together with a class to define selection. This is how it looks.

The script i use basically just selects the classes that have "selectable in the name" Which Works When the page loads. However It doesnt work when dynamic lists elements are created. I already tried using the body selector as well and while the non "folders" classes works, the nested ul elements dont seem to work anymore, after dynamic elements are created.

Here is a JSFiddle With my problem. Since the Library for the Drag aint hosted I included the src a script tag.

https://jsfiddle.net/9jak62of/

```js
$(".li-selectable").click(function () {


    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(".li-selectable").removeClass('active')
    }
    else {

            $(".li-selectable").removeClass('active')
            $(this).addClass('active')
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="list-group list" id="layers_list_group">
    <li class="list-group-item folder"><span>Paths</span>
        <ul class="list-group list">
            <li class="list-group-item li-selectable">BeginningPathBottom</li>
            <li class="list-group-item li-selectable">BeginningPathMid</li>
            <li class="list-group-item li-selectable">BeginningPathTop</li>
            <li class="list-group-item li-selectable">ConveyorBeltPath</li>
            <li class="list-group-item li-selectable">Path1</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item li-selectable">Assets_1</li>
    <li class="list-group-item li-selectable">Collision</li>
    <li class="list-group-item li-selectable">MainObjs</li>
    <li class="list-group-item li-selectable">Placeholder_Indicators</li>
    <li class="list-group-item li-selectable">CAMERABLOCK</li>
    
    <li class="list-group-item folder"><span>Layer1</span>
        <ul class="list-group list">
            <li class="list-group-item li-selectable">LavaTiles</li>
            <li class="list-group-item li-selectable">Layer1_TOP</li>
            <li class="list-group-item li-selectable">Layer1_MAIN</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    
    <li class="list-group-item li-selectable">Layer2</li>
    <li class="list-group-item li-selectable">Layer3</li>
    <li class="list-group-item li-selectable">Layer4</li>
    <li class="list-group-item li-selectable">Layer5</li>
    <li class="list-group-item li-selectable">Layer6</li>
    <li class="list-group-item li-selectable">Placeholder_Tilesets</li>
    <li class="list-group-item li-selectable">Background</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: I just tried it but it doesnt seem to work still. I included a JSfiddle if you want to have a look.https://jsfiddle.net/9jak62of/

Comment: Your fiddle is giving errors VM115 bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined

Comment: You need event delegation because `$("li").click` only applies to elements that exist at the time.  However your code has a `return e.stopPropagation();` in the `init:` which.. well.. stops propagation of the click event, so the click handler on the parent (at document.on(click, .li-selectable)) doesn't trigger because the event has been stopped.    Remove `return e.stopPropagation();` and it works.  Or better yet, add your code to that event handler `_fn` in `init:`

Comment: The alternative to event delegation is to add the events after adding the elements to the doc - this is what your `init:` in `expList` is doing - after you add the elements you call expList() which adds events to the new elements.  You could do the same in your code.

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind click event handler for dyncamically created elements using below code

```
$(document).on('click',".li-selectable", function () {
  
    /*if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(".li-selectable").removeClass('active')
    }
    else {
        
            $(".li-selectable").removeClass('active')
            $(this).addClass('active')
    }*/
    //improvement in above script
     $(this).toggleClass('active');
     $(".li-selectable").not(this).removeClass('active')
});
```

Comment: I just added a js fiddle and included the code you posted, It does not seem to work with  or without dynamically created tags. Im starting to wonder if maybe it has something to do with the Collapsible script. I included it on the page near the top in the the jsfiddle  if you want to have a look. 
https://jsfiddle.net/9jak62of/

Comment: looks like click event of `li-selectable` have been override by the third party library you have used because when i remove `$('.list').expList();` from the script it works. see this https://jsfiddle.net/dkpconh2/1/